# My laptop is becoming slower at times, how can I figure out if it is a hardware or a software issue?

Tags: 13.04, performance, thinkpad, cpu-load

Over the last month my 15 month old laptop has started showing me 100 % CPU utilization.

I used to have ubuntu 12.10 on it. I did a clean install of Ubuntu 13.04 on it and it was fine for a while.

I run pycharm, a couple of django servers, mongodb, mysql, chrome, firefox, a music player etc. My computer usage has not changed over the last year. I have run 12.04 and 12.10 very comfortably before this.

My previous laptop got screwed over 3 years and I am suspecting the same is happening here as well, but I can not see anything, like the laptop overheating etc.

I have a thinkpad 420i with i3 processor and 8 gigs of RAM

It shows CPU utilization for about 10 minutes after startup. I have to confess that I start all my programs with a single bash script.

After that the system usually behaves well but sometimes it starts to annoy me again.

The question is that I want to investigate and figure out if it is software issue or hardware issue. If it is hardware, I want to get stuff fixed before everything goes South. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use htop what's going on your system.

**[htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/)** displays all the running process in the system ordered by certain columns. This displays the information real-time CPU Usage, Memory Usage and Swap Usage

[image]

`man htop` will give all usage detail.

Comment: I know how to see the cpu utilization. What I need is a way to determine if there is any issue with the system because it is showing cpu usage at 100% for all CPUs

Comment: Please be clear on what you are asking Ranjith. While 100% utilisation is not necessarily a bad thing, prolonged 100% utilisation may be signs of an "issue with the system". As per Achu's initial post, start with identifying the processes that are behaving badly and continue from there. Look here : http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/forensic-analysis-live-linux-system-pt-1 and here: http://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/linux-performance-analysis-and-tools